# Getting null values when i map using autoMapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper, automapping

These are my Attribute Models

```
    public class MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyModel
{
    public MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyModel()
    {
        FlightIndex = new List<MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyFlightIndexModel>();

    }
    public List<MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyFlightIndexModel> FlightIndex
    { get; set; }

}

public class MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyFlightIndexModel
{
    public MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyFlightIndexModel()
    {
        RequestedSegmentRef = new OriginAndDestinationRequestType6Model();
        GroupOfFlights = new List<MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyFlightIndexGroupOfFlightsModel>();
    }
    public OriginAndDestinationRequestType6Model RequestedSegmentRef { get; set; }
    public List<MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyFlightIndexGroupOfFlightsModel> GroupOfFlights { get; set; }
}

public class OriginAndDestinationRequestType6Model
{
    public string SegRef { get; set; }
}

 public class MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyFlightIndexGroupOfFlightsModel
{
    public MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyFlightIndexGroupOfFlightsModel()
    {
        FlightDetails = new List<MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyFlightIndexGroupOfFlightsFlightDetailsModel>();
    }
    public List<MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyFlightIndexGroupOfFlightsFlightDetailsModel> FlightDetails { get; set; }
}

public class MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyFlightIndexGroupOfFlightsFlightDetailsModel
{
    public MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyFlightIndexGroupOfFlightsFlightDetailsModel()
    {
        FlightInformation = new TravelProductType2Model();
    }
    public TravelProductType2Model FlightInformation { get; set; }
}

public class TravelProductType2Model
{
    public TravelProductType2Model()
    {
        ProductDateTime = new ProductDateTimeType8Model();
        Location = new List<LocationIdentificationDetailsType2Model>();
        CompanyId = new CompanyIdentificationType8Model();
        ProductDetail = new AdditionalProductDetailsType3Model();
        AddProductDetail = new ProductFacilitiesType2Model();
    }
    public ProductDateTimeType8Model ProductDateTime { get; set; }
    public List<LocationIdentificationDetailsType2Model> Location { get; set; }
    public CompanyIdentificationType8Model CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string FlightOrtrainNumber { get; set; }
    public AdditionalProductDetailsType3Model ProductDetail { get; set; }
    public ProductFacilitiesType2Model AddProductDetail { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public string FlightName { get; set; }
    public string CabinName { get; set; }
}

public class LocationIdentificationDetailsType2Model
{
    public string LocationId { get; set; }
    public string AirportCityQualifier { get; set; }
    public string Terminal { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyIdentificationType8Model
{
    public string MarketingCarrier { get; set; }
    public string OperatingCarrier { get; set; }
}

public class AdditionalProductDetailsType3Model
{
    public string EquipmentType { get; set; }
    public string OperatingDay { get; set; }
    public string TechStopNumber { get; set; }
    //public List<string> LocationId { get; set; }
}

public class ProductFacilitiesType2Model
{
    public string LastSeatAvailable { get; set; }
    public string LevelOfAccess { get; set; }
    public string ElectronicTicketing { get; set; }
    public string OperationalSuffix { get; set; }
    public string ProductDetailQualifier { get; set; }
    //public List<string> FlightCharacteristic { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDateTimeType8Model
{
    //public string TypeOfAircraft { get; set; }
    public string ArrivalDate { get; set; }
    public string ArrivalTime { get; set; }
    public string DepartureDate { get; set; }
    public string DepartureTime { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
}
```

and these are my viewModels

```
    public class SearchReplyModel
{
    public SearchReplyModel()
    {
        Flights = new List<Flights>();
    }
    public List<Flights> Flights { get; set; }
}

public class Flights
{
    public Flights()
    {
        GroupOfFlights = new List<GroupOfFlights>();
    }
    public List<GroupOfFlights> GroupOfFlights { get; set; }
}

public class GroupOfFlights
{
    public GroupOfFlights()
    {
        FlightDetails = new List<FlightDetails>();
    }
    public string RefNumber { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public List<FlightDetails> FlightDetails { get; set; }
}

public class FlightDetails
{
    public string ArrivalDate { get; set; }
    public string ArrivalTime { get; set; }
    public string DepartureDate { get; set; }
    public string DepartureTime { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public string FromCity { get; set; }
    public string ToCity { get; set; }
    public string Terminal { get; set; }
    public string FlightNumber { get; set; }
    public string FlightName { get; set; }
    public string ElectronicTicketing { get; set; }
    public string EquipmentType { get; set; }
}
```

And i tried this..

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ProductDateTimeType8Model,Centra.Core.Model.Fare.FlightDetails>().ForMember(x=>x.ArrivalDate,c=>c.MapFrom(p=>p.ArrivalDate));
Mapper.CreateMap<ProductDateTimeType8Model,Centra.Core.Model.Fare.FlightDetails>().ForMember(x => x.ArrivalTime, c => c.MapFrom(p => p.ArrivalTime));

Mapper.CreateMap<ProductDateTimeType8Model,Centra.Core.Model.Fare.FlightDetails>().ForMember(x => x.DepartureDate, c => c.MapFrom(p => p.DepartureDate));

Mapper.CreateMap<ProductDateTimeType8Model,Centra.Core.Model.Fare.FlightDetails().ForMember(x => x.DepartureTime, c => c.MapFrom(p => p.DepartureTime));

Mapper.CreateMap<ProductDateTimeType8Model,Centra.Core.Model.Fare.FlightDetails().ForMember(x => x.Duration, c => c.MapFrom(p => p.Duration));

Mapper.CreateMap<MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyFlightIndexGroupOfFlightsFlightDetailsModel, Centra.Core.Model.Fare.FlightDetails>();
Mapper.CreateMap<MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyFlightIndexGroupOfFlightsModel, Centra.Core.Model.Fare.GroupOfFlights>();

Mapper.CreateMap<MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyFlightIndexModel, Flights>();

Mapper.CreateMap<MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyModel, SearchReplyModel>().ForMember(x => x.Flights, c => c.MapFrom(p => p.FlightIndex));

var jsonResult = new JsonResult() { Data=response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Response>().Result };
SearchReplyModel searchReplyModel=Mapper.Map<SearchReplyModel(jsonResult.Data);
```

When i try to Automap FlightDetails, i am getting all null values and is their any alternative way to do it?
i am not aware of how to implement this in ValueResolver,can anyBody please help me out to rectify this!

Comment: Do we really need *all that code* to demonstrate the problem? Can't you narrow it down to a smaller example?

Comment: And code that is properly formatted so its readable.

Comment: i wanted to show all the `classes` because every `class` is linked with the other one so thats the reason i did this.

Comment: Am i doing the autoMapping correctly or not? Is their any other way to do this?

Comment: @syed-rasheed It appears that you are trying to flatten the numerous models and this is where AutoMapper can help. A smaller example will really help as stated in the previous comment. The mapping does look incorrect in much of your example. You can chain the ProductDateTimeType8Model to FlightDetails for example.

Comment: @Jerode you said correct but, if i chain ProductDateTimeType8Model to FilightDetails i get only some attributes but the remaining are from other models and actually i  shortened my question before posting it, and you asked for an example, you just help me out to map all FlightDetails to my viewModel thats what i want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of mapping some of the other properties where it can be figured out with what you posted:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ProductDateTimeType8Model, FlightDetails>()
    .ForMember(x => x.ArrivalDate, c => c.MapFrom(p => p.ArrivalDate))
    .ForMember(x => x.ArrivalTime, c => c.MapFrom(p => p.ArrivalTime))
    .ForMember(x => x.DepartureDate, c => c.MapFrom(p => p.DepartureDate))
    .ForMember(x => x.DepartureTime, c => c.MapFrom(p => p.DepartureTime))
    .ForMember(x => x.Duration, c => c.MapFrom(p => p.Duration));

Mapper.CreateMap<MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyFlightIndexGroupOfFlightsFlightDetailsModel, FlightDetails>()
    .ForMember(x => x.FlightName, c => c.MapFrom(p => p.FlightInformation.FlightName))
    .ForMember(x => x.FlightNumber, c => c.MapFrom(p => p.FlightInformation.FlightOrtrainNumber));

Mapper.CreateMap<MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyModel, SearchReplyModel>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Flights, c => c.MapFrom(p => p.FlightIndex));
```

The Mapper.CreateMap just defines the mapping, calling the Mapper.Map will map the object when called. So you could do something along the lines of

```
var myInitialModel = new MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReplyFlightIndexGroupOfFlightsFlightDetailsModel();
var myDateTiomeModel = new ProductDateTimeType8Model();

FlightDetails myResult = Mapper.Map(myInitialModel, new FlightDetails());
myResult = Mapper.Map(myDateTiomeModel, myResult);
```

I hope this gets you on the right track. After this example `myResult` should have `FlightName` and `FlightNumnber` filled in as well as the initial ones.

Comment: this is what i wanted...Thanks for you time :)